# What configuration of JBoss should we used - web, standard, default?

Tags: configuration, jboss

We develop web application and we are going to deploy it on JBoss.
Now we use JSF, Facelets, Webflow, JMX, Spring. 
We are going to use JMS(ActiveMQ). 
Maybe in the future we will use EJB3. But for near future we will not use it.

What configuration of JBoss would be better to use - web, standard, default? 
And why?

Comment: I am interested in any docs explaining the difference between "standard" and "default"...

Answer (score 1):

Go for the smallest config that does what you need. The "web" configuration seems to have everything you need, including ejb3 support.

Remember, the configurations in the distribution are just examples. It's perfectly acceptable to create custom server configs by copying the deployers and libs around to produce a config that does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I've never found the need to use anything other than default, sometimes removing some of the config. And that's included JMS, EJB, Spring, Webflow, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I you are using JBoss AS 5.1.X, I recommend this book: [http://www.amazon.com/JBoss-AS-Development-Marchioni-Francesco/dp/1847196829](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847196829) 
On page 31 there is a detailed explanation about the five provided configurations.